# What's the msbuild path to Exec tlbimp from a csproj?

Tags: c#, msbuild, tlbimp

I want to run a prebuild target which I'm coding up in a csproj. This needs to run tlbimp to produce a dll my project references.

I'm trying to exec tlbimp, but am getting errors that it can't be found. Is there an msbuild variable or environment variable I can use to deduce the path to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might not be a direct variable, but you can use some built-in variables to construct the path. As on my machine, I have tlbim.exe in multiple locations:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\TlbImp.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\TlbImp.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\TlbImp.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\x64\TlbImp.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\TlbImp.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\TlbImp.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\TlbImp.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\x64\TlbImp.exe

And I can use my desired Tlbim.exe using Windows default environment variables for "C:\Program files" folder as:

**"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\Tlbimp.exe"**

In Msbuild projects, you will have to use $(var) instead of %var%, so it should be like:

**"$(ProgramFiles(x86))\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64\Tlbimp.exe"**

Hope you got the idea...

Answer (score 4):

With MSBuild 12 (VS2013),

```
$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)
```

points to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\
```

i.e. `tlbimp.exe` is at

```
&quot;$(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)tlbimp.exe&quot;
```

([Where is this defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569589/where-is-the-targetframeworksdktoolsdirectory-was-defined))