# where is the "TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory" was defined

Tags: msbuild

I was using msbuild build my sln and get error message "couldn't find 'AxImp.exe' which already exists under %Program files (x86)%\Microsoft sdks\windows\v8.1A. but seems it find sdk from v8.0A, output info point out the error was in Microsoft.Common.targets file(code see below). I didn't found where the "TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory" was defined, anyone can help me?

environment: winblue(4.5.1 sdk v8.1A) without visual studio.

```
    <ResolveComReference
      TypeLibNames="@(COMReference)"
      TypeLibFiles="@(COMFileReference)"
      ResolvedAssemblyReferences="@(ReferencePath)"
      WrapperOutputDirectory="$(InteropOutputPath)"
      IncludeVersionInInteropName="$(IncludeVersionInInteropName)"
      KeyContainer="$(KeyContainerName)"
      KeyFile="$(KeyOriginatorFile)"
      DelaySign="$(DelaySign)"
      StateFile="@(_ResolveComReferenceCache)"
      TargetFrameworkVersion="$(TargetFrameworkVersion)"
      TargetProcessorArchitecture="$(ProcessorArchitecture)"
      NoClassMembers="$(ComReferenceNoClassMembers)"
      Silent="$(ResolveComReferenceSilent)"
      EnvironmentVariables="$(ResolveComReferenceEnvironment)"
      **SdkToolsPath="$(ResolveComReferenceToolPath)"**
      ExecuteAsTool="$(ComReferenceExecuteAsTool)"
      MSBuildArchitecture="$(ResolveComReferenceMSBuildArchitecture)"
      ContinueOnError="$(ContinueOnError)">

  <**ResolveComReferenceToolPath** Condition="'$(ResolveComReferenceToolPath)' == ''">$(**TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory**)</ResolveComReferenceToolPath>
```

Answer (score 7):

Depends on the version and platform you're targeting, but latest is at `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\Microsoft.NetFramework.CurrentVersion.props`, follow your imports, i.e. `<Import Project=".targets" />`. To get the values run MSBuild with `/v:diag` and all evaluated properties will be dumped and the start.

Comment: Depending on your tools you will get a path similar to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\

Comment: I'm running MSBuild with /v:diag as you suggest and TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory is blank on my build agent. Any idea how I start troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1):

what ended up working for me was installing:

**Windows Software Development kit (SDK) for windows 8**

*even though I'm on widows server 2016*

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-sdk

I guess the clue was in my error:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2428, 5): error MSB3086: Task could not find "LC.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed